# Having multiple tableViews in a scrollview with paging makes tableHeaderView's searchBar non touchable

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have 5 tableViewControllers using UISearchResultsUpdating protocol with the new UISearchController

```
private var resultSearchController:UISearchController!
  resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
  resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
  resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
  resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
  tableView.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar
  tableView.tableHeaderView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
  tableView.tableHeaderView?.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

When I load this viewController by pushing it on top of other viewControllers, everything works fine. I can touch the cells, I can touch the searchBar and operate a search.

Now, when I put 5 (or less, it doesn't matter) of those tableViewControllers inside a controller containing a scrollView

```
let rect: CGRect = self.view.frame
scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: rect)
scrollView.pagingEnabled = true

scrollView.addSubview(oneTableViewController)
scrollView.addSubview(twoTableViewController)...
```

- I can navigate through the 5 tableViewController by swiping left and right.
- I can select a row in any tableview.
- but I can't touch the searchBar anymore...

I tried to set:

- scrollView.exclusiveTouch = false
- ensure that tableView.tableHeaderView?.userInteractionEnabled = true

Any ideas?

Comment: note: when I touch the searchBar, searchBarShouldBeginEditing: is called and I return true (I tried with false too...) but nothing happens. keyboard is not even showing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to do such thing, don't forget to add the tableViewControllers as childViewControllers of your main ViewController.

```
self.addChildViewController(tableVC1)
tableVC1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
self.addChildViewController(tableVC2)
tableVC2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

now everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your problem I think there can be a better way to achieve what you are doing.

Instead of using 5 tableview in a scrollview, I will say use one tableview and you can set its cell to show data.. Now you can add scrollview in different cell and add your data on scrollview that will allow you to scroll left and right.

Otherwise if you wanna continue the same approach you are doing then,

1. you can rotate tableview to 90 degree so that it gives you a feel of left and right scrolling.
2. You can use your tableview'd delegate:

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 

   //do the check
   if tableView == YourTableView {
      //do your stuff. As you have indexPath you can get row at that   indexPath
          }
   }
   ```

Comment: The alternative solution is to use UIPageViewController but the question here is about why the searchBar doesn't work. Hard to debug.

Comment: PageViewController won't give you much control over longer run. I personally feel them as the dumb controls :P. If your searchBar is non touchable just check if any other controls frame is overlapping on it. As you said the searchBar was touchable but its not touchable after the search.. Try the "debug View hierarchy" while running the app